# How can I bind the hostBinding event to some nested element in the host?

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I have the following directive

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appAutocompleteCustom]',
  exportAs: 'appAutocompleteCustom'
})
export class AutocompleteCustomDirective {
 @HostBinding('class.border') isOpen = false;

 @HostListener('click', ['$event']) onClick(event) {
   this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
 }
}
```

so always when the host element is clicked i am toggling the isOpen property and giving class `border` to the host element.

That is great. But i want to have this hostListener on the main element, but the host binding to happens on some nested element inside. For example

```
<div #autoOne="appAutocompleteCustom">
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <div class="hostBindThis">lorem</div>
</div>
```

the div is the host here and when i click on the div hostListener gets triggered and also the host binding on that div.
How can i give the class `border` on `<div class="hostBindThis">lorem</div>` through hostBinding ?

I know that i can search for this through `document.getElementByClassName('hostBindThis')`, find it and give class but i wonder if there is some angular way ?

Answer (score 1):

Hostbinding is designed to be binded to the host not to the children of the host. You can't hostbind like that via directive.

Will not work:

```html
<div appAutocompleteCustom>
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <div class="hostBindThis">lorem</div>
</div>
```

Can work:

```html
<div>
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <div appAutocompleteCustom class="hostBindThis">lorem</div>
</div>
```

TS:

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[appAutocompleteCustom]',
  exportAs: 'appAutocompleteCustom'
})
export class AutocompleteCustomDirective {
 @HostBinding('class.border') isOpen = false;

 @HostListener('click', ['$event']) onClick(event) {
   console.warn(event.target)
  if (event.target.classList.contains('hostBindThis')) {
    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
   }
 }
}
```

However if we target the css selector to a child div it would seemingly do what you asked, though hostbinding is still on the host.

```css
.border > div {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hostlistener-imperative-2ppcax?file=src%2Fapp%2Fauto-complete.directive.ts